# Using CMIS, how do I access the change log from SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, cmis

I am using SharePoint 2010 and accessing it from CMIS. The repositoryInfo section does not include a changeLogToken element even though the capabilities element mentions objectidsonly.

Is there something special I need to enable on SP to get change log working?